# Is it possible to call a module with a variable function in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, module

Here's a bit more context, in python, how could you create this effect?

```
import random
variable = 'randint'
random.[variable](1,3)
```

Is there any way to write a code for this effect? I haven't found anything outside of a load of {if} blocks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getattr` built-in:

```
>>> import random
>>> variable = 'randint'
>>> getattr(random, variable)(1, 3)
3
>>>
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

> getattr(object, name[, default])
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the 
>   string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
>   raised.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up my knowledge of the getattr function too.

Answer (score 0):

just an alternative of using `getattr`:

```
In [141]: random.__dict__['randint'](1,3)
Out[141]: 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that may be useful for other stuff I'm working on as well.